# Queueing at Wimbledon for a Grounds Pass: When Can I Expect to Get In?

Tags: tennis, fans, wimbledon, spectators

I wish to get a grounds pass for Wimbledon. My plan was to get to the queue at about 7am. I have seen some people say that I wouldn't get in until 1pm doing so, however they are talking about show court tickets.

I only want a grounds pass, not a show court ticket. Approximately how long would I have to wait if I arrived early in the morning?

Is there a different queue for grounds passes compared with show court tickets?

Comment: The advice you got in [tripadvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.za/ShowTopic-g186338-i17-k11713260-Queueing_for_Wimbledon_Grounds_Pass-London_England.html) might be the one to take. You must have checked this [How To Queue For Wimbledon](https://londonist.com/london/sport/how-to-queue-for-wimbledon).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about getting a ticket to a sporting event

Comment: I think this is a good point to raise on meta, whether questions regarding spectators to what is clearly a competitive sports activity are on-topic. FTR I say it is, and edited this question to be suitable.

Comment: Capitalising random words in a sentence is not grammatical, and when done to a title, makes it difficult to read. @SamT

Comment: Actually, because it's a *title*, it is fine to do so (well, not just random words of course!) :) -- these days it's more a style thing, some people prefering 'title case', with others prefering 'sentence case'; I personally use title case. For further details, see these links: https://proofreadmyessay.co.uk/writing-tips/title-case-sentence-case-headings/ or http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/capital_letters_title_case.htm

Comment: "Style" is a terrible excuse for bad grammar and making it harder to read.

Comment: Actually, as I pointed out, with supporting links, it's gramatically *correct*...